# How can I divide a vector into two equal vectors?

Tags: matlab

I need to divide a vector into two equal vector in MATLAB. Could you help me please?
For example if I have the vector `x=[1 3 7 9]` and I need two split it into `y=[1 3]` and `z=[7 9]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function [v1, v2] = DivideVectorIntoTwo (v)
   midindex =  floor (length (v) / 2) ;
   v1 = v (1:midindex) ;
   v2  = v (midindex+1 :end) ;
end
```

Comment: nice idea to place it inside a function. +1

Comment: If you're making it a function, then either split along a specified dimension, or check the number of dimensions and throw an error if greater than 1...

Comment: @Dan you are right, but on the other side his function is called DivideVectorIntoTwo... So i guess you could argument, that it is meant for vectors only, which by definition are 1-dim.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to check out some basic matlab operations.

if you take vector `x`

```
x=1:1000;
```

you can easily split him into different new arrays. If you want to have to arrays with the same length you should use `numel()` or `size()` to get the size and then take half of it.

```
length_of_x=numel(x);
new_length=ceil(length_of_x/2);
```

I used `ceil()` (rounding up) in case your x has not the length: 2,4,6,8 and so on but 1,3,5... Then you can use `1:new_length` to get the first half and `new_length+1:end` for the later half.

```
x1=x(1:new_length);
x2=x(newlength+1:end);
```

would be the result for your task.

Answer (score 0):

`end` is a clever command in MATLAB that can be used as a shortcut in many situations, for instance when you want to take only the first half of a vector, like this:

```
v(1:end/2);
```

You can split a vector into two by using `deal` in an anonymous function handle:

```
split_vec = @(x) deal(x(1:floor(end/2)), x(floor(end/2)+1:end));

[a, b] = split_vec(1:10)
a =
     1     2     3     4     5
b =
     6     7     8     9    10
```